# Kong gateway header allow list / whitelist

Tags: kong

I want my Kong gateway to only allow certain headers in the request to be sent to the upstream server. Effectively a header whitelist. Is there a way to do this? I can't find any plugins for this.

Comment: Allowing certain headers in the request to be sent to the upstream and whitelisting using headers are not really the same idea. Do you just want to cut some headers out? or stop the request completely when some headers are in the request? 
For removing some headers `request-transformer` can be used.

Comment: As far as I can see, the Request Transformer plugin https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer/ can add or remove headers you explicitly specify. But I  want to allow only a set of known headers through and ignore any other headers.